# Dynamic programing mcm

Tags: algorithm

I am stuck with an assignment problem
Argue and prove that matrix chain multiplication exhibit optimal substructure property. I understand the concept but I am not getting how to prove it on paper.Any help will be great relief.

Comment: There's an excellent explanation of this algorithm in the book "Introduction to Algorithms", read it there

Comment: What have you tried so far? If you demonstrate that you've made an effort to solve this problem on your own and outline what you've attempted, we'll be better poised to help out.